# Sending a fetch request while connected to an iOT device without internet

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, fetch, iot, access-point

I'm developing an iOS app using Ionic (JavaScript Framework) and I'm connecting to an Iot device and sending a fetch request to it.

If my phone doesn't have a cellular connection, the fetch fails.

This is the process:

1. Turn on Iot device
2. Use app to connect to device access point
3. Send fetch request to device

   ```
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.1/');
      // handle response
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      // handle error
   }
   ```
4. Fetch fails

Is there a way for the fetch to work when connected to an access point without internet? Are there any other libraries that might help me achieve this?

Comment: I think this is a network issue not a framework issue, It should be possible that you can connect/fetch from the iot device if you are on the same local network as the iot device.

Comment: Can you visit the page of the iot device on a browser while connected to the access point?

Comment: Yeah that's correct.  The Iot device is acting like a router.  I am able to connect to it, but as soon as I send the fetch request, it fails.

Comment: When I connect to the device on my phone without cellular, I can go to the page of the Iot device on the browser and it works. It also works when doing it from my computer.

Comment: When you are on cellular data you are no longer on the same network as the device so you will not be able to communicate with it.

Comment: Well it does work when I have cellular turned on and connect to the device.  I just assumed that the WiFi connection would take precedence.

Comment: The address 'http://192.168.1.1/' is in the local ip address space and so will not really be reachable on a cellular network.

Comment: i have two devices a mac and iphone. i connect them both to the iot device respberry pi 4. when i do request form my macbook it working fine but when i do request from my app..it is not working. always network error. any solution for this